# What is faster - replaceWith or insertAfter (and hiding old element) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, replacewith, insertafter

I want to change some elements on the page. (for example I'll change inputs to divs' structures).

What is faster? To do it with replaceWith(). Or to insert div structure after the input, and then hide input?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.jsperf.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talking about something like an inline editing function I would use...

```
replaceWith()
```

Otherwise you'd be duplicating content on your page which may cause other problems.

EDIT: In some cases I also use...

```
.empty().html()
```

All really depends on what you're trying to accomplish though.

EDIT: Here is a fiddle based on your comment...

http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/WgjL5/2/

I would still go with `replaceWith()` instead of having multiple instances of a button in your code.

Comment: I change all `<input type='button'>' on my page to some divs (div-structure that make a button that I need)

Comment: @wdm Why do you do `empty()` first? `html()` already replaces everything.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made some tests with my script, and JS profiler showed no real difference between them (in speed I mean). So I prefer `replaceWith` in that script.